# S3 streaming video

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming, video-streaming

I have a simple question. I see that there are a lot of examples of video streaming from s3.
My question is can you stream a partially uploaded file to s3. 
While user A is uploading the file User B is downloading it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you're only using S3.

Uploads either succeed totally or fail. The file does not 'exist' on S3 until the entire file is uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

It may well be possible, but you'd probably be better off using something like the approach described here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LiveStreamingUsingAmazonCloudFront.html